# Missing \begin{document} in dantelogo.sty? Viccuad-CV

Tags: fonts, errors

I am trying to recompile my CV using the Viccuad-CV template on a new PC, but I keep running into bugs. I downloaded the template again and I am using the empty example to compile it but it keeps returning with the same error:

"Missing \begin{document}"

The empty example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{viccuad-cv}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\hypersetup{
pdftitle={John Doe resumé}, 
pdfauthor={John Doe}, 
pdfcreator={John Doe}, 
pdfsubject={Resumé}, 
pdfkeywords={PDF,LaTeX,John,Johny,resume,cv}
}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\setffdraftcolor}{\color[gray]{0.1}}
\header{}{}{header(static)}
\footer{footer(static)}
aside
\newpage
main1
\newpage
main2
\newpage
rest of text

\end{document}
```

Now I already looked at the answers for that error on here and I went back and made sure there were no BOM characters, I even retyped the whole tex file from scratch and it keeps coming up.

[image]

Double clicking on the error opens the dantelogo.sty file, and points to the following section:

```
\if@tempswa% we have (pdf)latex
 \message{We run (pdf)latex ... }%
 \PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc}%
 \RequirePackage{fontenc}%
 \def\dante@font{\fontencoding{\encodingdefault}\fontfamily{dante}\selectfont}%
\else
 \message{We run (lua)xelatex ... }%
 \RequirePackage{fontspec}
 \newfontfamily\dante@font{DANTE}%
  [Extension=.otf,
   BoldFont=*-Bold,
    ItalicFont=*-Italic,
     BoldItalicFont=*-Bold-Italic]
\fi
```

I have already gone and made sure that the .otf files are installed, the plain.otf and the bold-italic are installed. Everytime I install the italic or bold file it disappears again but I do not think this is causing the error.

If you have any ideas please let me know. Thanks.

Edit: Added log file:  [Log](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=7B538E950C98B53A%21199)

Comment: Running your example with the class from https://github.com/viccuad/viccuad-cv I got no errors.  Can you post the log file you get.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Hi, I have added a log file. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what is happening, but after line 816 in your log, my log contains `. 
. * 'bold small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:' before the `......`  May be the `DANTE-Bold-Italic.otf' is not loading???

Comment: @AndrewSwann I have tried replacing the fonts several time, are they supposed to be put anywhere other than installed in the fonts folder on Windows? I had downloaded the DANTELOGO package from the Miktex Pacakge Manager and tried reloading it.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have access to a windows machine.  I hope someone else can help.

Comment: Could you try running the update wizard? You've got an older version of `fontspec` and I suspect some syntax changes there are responsible.

Comment: @ObadahFahmy did you try the update wizard? Was there any change in the result?